# How to add save another Schema data to a model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using mongoose with Mongodb v3.4.3

Below is my image model code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const CoordinateSchema = require("./coordinate");

const ImageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    image_filename: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    image_url: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    coordinates: [CoordinateSchema],
});
```

Below is my CoordinateSchema code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const CoordinateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    coordinates : {
        type: Array,
        default: [],
    }
});

module.exports =  CoordinateSchema;
```

Below is my api js code running on express,

```
    router.post('/receiveCoordinates.json', (req, res, next) => {

        Image.findOneAndUpdate({image_filename:req.body.file_name}).then((image) =>    {


       })
    });
```

How to finish this code  so I can store coordinates data in Image model.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: @JoseLopezGarcia I am using Mongodb v3.4.3. and I update the question which I find out I can use findOneAndUpdate

Comment: I asked about your mongoose version, not MongoDB! By the way check my answer, if it doesn't work let me know so we can work out a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

To update the coordinates inside of findOneAndUpdate, you simply check that the returned document isn't undefined (which would mean your image wasn't found). Modify your api.js code like so:

```
router.post('/receiveCoordinates.json', (req, res, next) => {
    Image.findOneAndUpdate({image_filename:req.body.file_name}).then((image) => {
        if (!image) return Promise.reject(); //Image not found, reject the promise
        image.where({_id: parent.children.id(_id)}).update({coordinates: req.body.coordinates}) //Needs to be an array
            .then((coords) => {
                if (!coords) return Promise.reject();
                //If you reach this point, everything went as expected
            });
    }).catch(() => {
        console.log('Error occurred');
    );
});
```

---

Here's my guess why it isn't working.

In `ImageSchema`, you are sub-nesting **an array of** `CoordinateSchema`. But CoordinateSchema is a document which **already contains an array**.

This is probably not what you're looking for. If you're using *mongoose version 4.2.0 or higher*, you can nest CoordinateSchema inside of ImageSchema as a single document. Re-write your ImageSchema like this:

```
// ...

const ImageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // ...
    coordinates: CoordinateSchema,
});
```

If this didn't work or doesn't resolve your issue, please let me know so we can work together to find a solution.

Comment: Thanks man. I update the question which I find out I can use findOneAndUpdate but don't know how to finish it

Comment: What do you want to do after finding one?

Comment: Ok I'll modify the answer

Comment: I wrote the update off the top of my head (I'm travelling and didn't bring my workstation with me). Try the code and tell me what error it throws at you, if any

Comment: Really appreciated!

Comment: Tell me if it works or what error it throws at you! (Make sure that req.body.params is an array; if not, convert it into an array before calling .update()). And I helped in any way, consider giving an upvote ;)